# python : copy module code to the script

Tags: python, import, module

I have this script file (called `old_script.py`)

```
from module_test import hello
hello()
```

and this module (`module_test/__init__.py`)

```
def hello():
    print "hello"
```

how I can replace the import in the script with the code in module ?

and get a new script file (`new_script.py`) with a copy of the imported module code, like

```
def hello():
    print "hello"
hello()
```

I try make one single file to distribution.

Comment: You want the script to run the same code as the module, or you want to modify the definition of `hello` that was created in the module in your script? Its not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I try to make a new script file with the merge of old script file and the module content

Comment: ... maybe use templates ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you meaning you just what your code to be like?:

```
import hello
```

If so take a look [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).